# In PHP, How to handle a model without a view in an MVC-based app?

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller

I have a web app I want to convert to MVC based on the [Nathan Davidson MVC-Framework](http://www.nathandavison.com/article/11/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-1-introduction). I would like to know how **in general** I can manage a model that do not need a view, **and particularly**, a database class.

I realize it would be more understandable with an example. I have a basic `Database` class that within the constructor - creates a connection to the database, within the destructor - closes that connection, and contains a `query` method that executes an SQL query:

```
class Database
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fanfiction");

        if(mysqli_connect_error())
           die("Connection faild: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->conn);
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        return mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
    }
}
```

That class is used by three classes: `Search`, `Create`, and `Update`. Each of them analyzes the end-user input, manipulates it, and uses the `query` method to execute some actions based on the results. The problem is that none of them is visible to the end-user, so there is not a View for any of them.

I thought I could just use a Model without associating it with any View, but the `BaseController` (An abstruct class for all Controllers to inherit from) is always creating an instance of the View class (Which of course, handle the View aspect of the app), so I must associate it with a View.

So - now more understandable - my questions are the follow:

1. **In general - In a MVC-based app, how to handle a model that has no view?**
2. **In my particular case - hot to handle the database? How to organize my files and classes?**

I google it but I could not find any reference to that issue, so I hope I am not re-asking an answered question.

Hope it's not too stupid questions. Thank you again.

Comment: The entire point of an MVC separation is that each part is independent. There's no default association between models, controllers and views. You code each independently as needed and pull them together as necessary.

Comment: Well, there isn't any connection between the Model and the View. That happends indeed only in the controller.The problem is that in that specifc framework, all controlers must have a view. So my question is how to handle it.

Comment: Use a different framework!? ;-P

Comment: I am pretty new to the MVC logic, so I try to use a simple MVC framework. But my questions remain unchanged no matter what framework I use. How to handle a function in that app that does need a model but not a view? And why the heck someone downgrade my question? I believe it's pretty good. :(

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Models are not connected to views, I thought we've established that. There's an n:m relationship between models and views. You may have 5 models which all contribute to 1 view, or 1 model which is used in 5 views, or many models which have no view, or many views which have no models. You said *every controller requires a view*. That's a different story. Controller actions in web frameworks typically correspond to HTTP requests. It makes sense that each HTTP request requires a response, a view. Do you agree? Is there a misunderstanding here?

Comment: Now i understand your point. Thanks a lot my friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's about you if you want to use model in view or no. You are not obligated to do so. If you want to manage database correctly you should use ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/).

I wouldn't advice to create your own MVC. There are a lot of frameworks that has it written already if you want something that can be used on enterprise level check Symfony2, Zend2 but there are also slim frameworks like: silex, slim etc.

Also there are plenty of packages on github that solves routing problems etc.

Model is something that represents data which may come for example from database. There is also Service which helps keeping logic from Controller.

So Controller may use model and should use view. 
Model just handles data
View shows data

You should not connect view to model or model to view, these things should happen in controller or even better in service.

Check this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Comment: As I said to [decceze](http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) - there isn't any connection between the Model and the View. That happends indeed only in the controller.The problem is that in that specifc framework,  all controlers must have a view. So my question is how to handle it. Thanks.

Comment: I think not view is  needed but response. This is what browser expects and this is what server gives. "This specific framework" has name?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, as I mentioned in the question: [Nathan Davidson MVC-Framework](http://www.nathandavison.com/article/11/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-1-introduction). Thanks again.